# How are set argument to nix-expression

Tags: nixos

I'm new to Nix and I'm trying to understand the [hello](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ex-hello-nix) derivation given in example.

I can understand the syntax and what is supposed to do, however I don't understand
how the initial arguments (and the especially the `perl` one_ are fed ?

I mean, who is setting the `perl` argument before calling this derivation.
Does that mean that `perl` is a dependency of `hello` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages are typically written as `set of dependencies -> derivation` functions, to be assembled later. The arguments you ask about are fed from pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix, which holds the set of all packages in Nixpkgs.

When you find the `hello`'s line in all-packages.nix, you'll notice it's using `callPackage` - it's signature is `path to Nix expression -> overrides -> derivation`. `callPackage` loads the path, looks at the function it loaded, and for each arguments provides either value from `overrides` or, if not given, from the huge set in all-packages.nix.

For a nice description of `callPackage` see http://lethalman.blogspot.com/2014/09/nix-pill-13-callpackage-design-pattern.html - it's a less condensed explanation, showing how you could have invented `callPackage` yourself :-).

Comment: In case the link dies, please add the summary of the link here if possible. Otherwise, great explanation!

Comment: Thanks! I added a note about what's under the link. I've already described the main point in the answer - I added that link as it's a more verbose explanation, in case mine is too condensed.

Comment: The whole nix-pill serie is great. Thanks for the link